# Docker run file not found

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to write a simple dockerfile that wraps around a bash script. The docker file looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY . /build/demo
WORKDIR /build/demo/
RUN pwd; ls
RUN chmod +x run-demo.sh
RUN run-demo.sh 1 zk
```

and the context file directory (slimmed down) looks like:

- Dockerfile
- build

  - demo

    - run-demo.sh

I have a step `RUN pwd; ls` which outputs

```
RUN pwd; ls
 ---> Running in f22ce9175cee
/build/demo
run-demo.sh
```

and yet once the `docker build .` reaches the last command, it says `/bin/sh: run-demo.sh: not found`. How is that possible? Thank you

edit: and the script begins with !#/bin/bash if thats relevant
edit2:

```
RUN pwd; ls -l
 ---> Running in 16fbda2c19e1
/build/demo
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           775 Jun 12 21:14 run-demo.sh
Removing intermediate container 16fbda2c19e1
 ---> bf8ada47953a
Step 7/7 : RUN ./run-demo.sh 1 zk
 ---> Running in daccefe3c895
/bin/sh: ./run-demo.sh: not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it. openjdk:8-jre-alpine, my base image, does not pack bash

Answer (score 0):

To run a program directly, as you are trying, it must be in one of the directories listed in the `PATH` variable. To run a file elsewhere you need to explicitly provide the path to it, as in either `./run-demo.sh` or `/build/demo/run-demo.sh`.

Comment: This was how I first wrote my docker file, it has no effect on the error

Comment: I added an edit to the question